# How to manually achieve a motion blur effect on a object in the compositor?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, effects, motion-blur

[image]

Is it possible to achieve this look I made with motion blur in the render panel similarly in the compositor without having to move the object?

Answer (score 2):

Use the directional blur node.

[image]

Form the [blender manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/compositing/types/filter/directional_blur.html?highlight=directional%20blur):

> **Iterations**
>
> Controls how may times the image is duplicated to create the blur effect. Higher values give smoother results.
>
> **Wrap**
>
> Wraps the image on the X and Y axis to fill in areas, that become transparent from the blur effect.
>
> **Center X, Y**
>
> Sets the position where the blur center is. This makes a difference if the angle, spin, and/or zoom are used.
>
> **Distance**
>
> How large the blur effect is.
>
> **Angle**
>
> Image is blurred at this angle from the center.
>
> **Spin**
>
> Rotates the image each iteration to create a spin effect, from the center point.
>
> **Zoom**
>
> Scales the image each iteration, creating the effect of a zoom.